# cakephp 2.0 custom query pagination

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am working on one project in cakephp 2.0. Here, I have one query in my model.

$sql = `SELECT Ad . *,Client.name,Keyword.keyword FROM`ads`Ad INNER JOIN pages Page ON ( Ad.page_id = Page.id ) INNER JOIN keywords Keyword ON ( Page.keyword_id = Keyword.id ) 
INNER JOIN clients Client ON ( Keyword.client_id = Client.id ) WHERE Ad.archived = 1`;

I want to do pagination using cakephp's pagination module. I check out its documentation and some other answers from google but not able to get how to implement it. can anyone tell me how to implement it ?

Comment: Kindly post your code. So that I can try to correct it.

Comment: I have tried to override the paginate functions in my model file. I passed my query in extra parameter <br>  
  public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1, $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {    
    return $this->query($extra['query']);
}

public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array()) {    
    $this->recursive = $recursive;
    $results = $this->query($extra['query']);
    return $results;
}. It give me internal error. but didn't show up what exactly the error is.

Comment: You should probably accept some previous answers. Other users are more willing to offer advice if they feel they have a good chance of being rewarded for their efforts

Answer (score 0):

[This CakePHP documentation page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) will help you to achieve the same as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: I was trying to do by it but it used $this->find() method for custom pagination. my problem is that I have a custom query which is used at many places. so if possible if I can use this query for pagination then it would be good for me else I have to make changes at many places in my code.

Comment: You can simply put that common method in your AppModel class. And you can also rename the method name so that it will not clash with your existing usage of this named function. You just have to invoke this method with any Model and it will work as a class method for that Model. I hope you get understand.